# Machine Learning: How can I include sensitivity or specificity in error calculation?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a working model of neural network used for classification. At the moment, I have applied cross-entropy to calculate an error between Test Outcome (model output) and Condition Outcome (true output). The model is used for binary classification but will be extended to handle multiple classes. So far, the error is calculated using cross-entropy in MATLAB:

`err = sum( y.*log(h(x)) + (1-y).*log(1-h(x)) )`

I would like the model to perform in such the way that it can classify or detect more False Positives then False Negatives. I know there is so-called **confusion matrix** where I can specify everything but I don't know how this could correspond to error calculation. Any suggestions are very welcome :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can weigh the positive class higher or lower than the negative class by introducing a scalar class weight. Since

```
y .* log(h(x))
```

represents the loss on the positive training samples and

```
(1 - y) .* log(1 - h(x))
```

is the loss on the negative training samples,

```
err = -sum(w .* y .* log(h(x)) + (1 - y) .* log(1 - h(x)))
```

causes the positive training samples to be more important than the negative ones when `w>1`, and less important when `w<1`. Make sure you modify the derivatives accordingly.

Comment: Thank you larsmans. I was wondering what you mean by loss on training samples. I guess I may not fully understand this equation. Also, my outputs are from the set {0,1}. If I increased the training number in calculation of the error by `w`, wouldn't I just get the set {w*1,0}? And then just get the output w*1 if the condition is positive? I am a little bit confused.